# Why can't I connect to SQL 2008 from Windows 7 without a hosts entry?

Tags: sql-server, windows-7

On new installs of Windows 7, we cannot connect to SQL 2008 instances--even by just IP addresss--without opening the firewall port 1433 and adding a hosts file.

The firewall port is obvious, but why does it only connect after adding a hosts entry for the SQL Server?

Answer (score 3):

Can the windows server ping the SQL box by name? i'm guessing not.

Sounds like a DNS (or firewall between DNS) issue.

Comment: (I updated the problem description) Before adding the hosts entry, we can't even connect by IP address.

Comment: I agree with it being a DNS problem. Perhaps you have an old DNS entry pointing to that IP that the host file circumvents.

Comment: Does SQL Server perform name resolution/validation every time you connect? Why can't I connect with just IP address?

Comment: hrm.
without the host entry, the output of 
`tracepath sql-server` (via its IP), and
`nslookup sql-server` might be interesting.

Comment: We do not have DNS entries for these servers. Also, it *seems* to only happen with named instances.

Comment: thats very, very strange.
What firewall do you have in the middle of it all? I'd go looking through the logs.

Also, what did you mean by 'it only seems to happen with named instances'?

Answer (score 0):

You are only experiencing the issue on named instances?  If that is the case check to see if the SQL Browser service is started. The Browser service is used to connect to named instances.